# PHP Pagination Safety

Tags: javascript, php, sql-injection

I have simple jTable jQuery webpage.
Since I didn't recieve much response in my previous topic:
[Safe MySQL password on shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725032/safe-mysql-password-on-shared-hosting), I've started to research on my own.
I'm using PHP based script for MySQL connection and for **Pagination**.
From what I've researched, queries with no input data from user can't be harmed by hacker unless the PHP file is directly accessed and/or replaced. Therefore I decided to put it above my web root.
I've added pagination feature for jTable, which uses SQL query with some input data from JS script.
For heaven's sake I decided to protect this query from any malicious SQL Injections.

The query:

```
"SELECT * FROM people LIMIT " . $_GET["jtStartIndex"] . "," . $_GET["jtPageSize"] . ";"
```

What I did is I've added casts to int, for ex:

```
"SELECT * FROM people LIMIT " . (int)$_GET["jtStartIndex"] . "," . (int)$_GET["jtPageSize"] . ";"
```

Is it safe enough?
As far as I remember, any string that will go there will be parsed to 0 by (int) cast.

Comment: Use mysqli or pdo with prepared statements to begin with

Comment: no, it's not safe. `order by 7` and whatnot makes very little sense.

Comment: Wouldn't cast to int from `order by 7` give 0 as we have letter first?

Comment: My bad, I've gave the example from jTable tutorial where sorting is used. Here I don't want to used sorting so I only want to secure data that is used in LIMIT. It's edited now. Note that query is an example only from jTable tutorials.

Comment: Why try to find alternative ways to [prevent SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)? This is a solved problem.

Comment: @deceze - Please correct me if I'm wrong: Am I doing the same as I would do with for example mysqli code:
`$stmt->bind_param('i', $startIndex);` ?

Comment: Yes, generally you'll get the same result. However, separating the query and binding the parameters is inherently safer. I tiny typo may subvert your manual casting entirely without you noticing. That's a lot harder with bound values.

Answer (score 1):

Some people think that prepared statement is the only way to be safe about sql injection, it is not true, doing a manual filter is also effective (but verbose).

In this case is fine the solution but it could be wrapper (for example for capturing errors)

```
<?php
// this function is not needing unless it is used recurrently.
function safe_get_int($value) { 
     return intval(@$_GET[$value]); 
}
$init= safe_get_int("jtStartIndex") ;
$page= safe_get_int("jtPageSize") ;
if (($init>0 && $init<=9999) && ($page>0 && $page<100)) {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM people LIMIT {$init},{$page};";
} else {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM people LIMIT 0,20;"; // standard value
}
?>
```

results:

entering a number = return the number.

entering a text   = return zero.

entering a special character = return zero.

missing the value = return zero.  (it is why i added the @).

entering a negative = it is considered as a zero value.

(added), entering a big number is also restricted. For example, a big page size could crash some server.

Comment: How is it better than (int) cast?

Comment: It's better to use `isset` versus the `@` error suppressor.

`function safe_get_int($value) {
    return isset($_GET[$value]) ? (int)$_GET[$value] : 0;
}`

Comment: Usually (int) is faster, i use intval just because the readability.